# Compress a file with JclCompression

Tags: delphi, compression, delphi-2010, jedi-code-library

I am trying to save (compress) a .zip file using `JclCompression` with the JCL Demo. When I press the Save button on the Read and Write Tab the demo calls:

```
procedure TFormMain.ActionSaveExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (FArchive as TJclCompressArchive).Compress;
  CloseArchive;
end;
```

When `(FArchive as TJclCompressArchive).Compress;` is executed it produces an exception: "At least one compression volumes could not be replaced after an archive out-of-place update."  Also sometimes when I press the save button, the "application is not responding" appears in the form's caption, so I have to shutdown the demo.

Is this code correct or do I have to change it to sucessfully compress and save the zip file?  Are there any other demos for `JclCompression` so I can learn how to use these classes?

Aside from this problem the demo seems to be working correctly.  I can open a zip file, create a new zip file, add files, add files from a directory, extract selected files, extract all, and get zip file properties. Saving seems to be a problem.

I am using Delphi 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: When mentioning problems with the JEDI JCL, please quote the exact VERSION you are using of the JCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue as jedi-jcl-compression-library-wont-open-spanned-archive-files.
[JEDI JCL Compression library wont open spanned archive files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566738/jedi-jcl-compression-library-wont-open-spanned-archive-files/7602687#7602687)

The JCL-JVCL version you use is **buggy**.
I would recommand to upgrade your JCL installation to [latest daily build](http://jcl.sourceforge.net/daily/)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this error message when files which I wanted to archive were opened for writing, so you need to close them or copy them to temp folder in advance. Also If you using function Create7zArchive() as i do you need 7z.dll placed in your bin output folder. It's sad, but it seems JCL doesn't use Zlib.pas which is already integrated in Delphi.

JCL 2.7.0.5676 (Stable)

Comment: I used Delphi 2007, Windows 7 x86.